# Как gRPС обрабатывает большое кол-во подключений?

Tags: python, golang, grpc

Не нашел нормального объяснения как gRPС обрабатывает большое кол-во одновременных подключений?

Нужно ли перед ним вешать веб сервер nginx и т.п. ? Или он сам выступает как веб сервер?

Нужно ли запускать большое кол-во потоков самому? Или это настраивается на уровне самого сервера gRPС кодом на том языке на котором пишешь?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наверное, речь идёт о `gRPC`.

`gRPC` сервер при подключении клиента создаёт новый сокет и вешает на него обработчик сообщений. То, как именно работают эти обработчики, зависит от языка программирования.

В `go` это горутины, и сам рантайм `go` определяет, в каких потоках их выполнять. Соответственно, в `go` обработчики нескольких подключений могут работать параллельно.

В `python` это пайтоновский потоки, но так как пайтон работает в однопоточном режиме, то их переключение осуществляется внутри рантайма и по факту в каждый момент времени выполняется не более одного такого обработчика.

### Краткий ликбез о том, как работают сокеты TCP

Раз у вас есть вопрос про "раздаёт на другие сокеты", то опишу кратенько как работают сервера поверх сокетов.

Сокеты TCP бывают двух видов - серверные и клиентские. Клиентские умеют подключаться к серверным и умеют передавать данные. Серверные сокеты не умеют передавать данные, но зато они могут ждать запросы на подключение от клиентов.

Как происходит подключение клиента к серверу.

На стороне сервера программа выполняет несколько системных вызовов: `bind` для связывания сокета с IP адресом и портом, и `listen` для переключения в hрежим серверного сокета, `accept` для ожидания подключений (в реальности, как правило, несколько сложнее, но для ликбеза несущественно).

Вызов `accept` блокируется до тех пор, пока не будет получен запрос на соединение от клиента. Когда клиент подключается, *внутри ядра* создаётся клиентский сокет для обмена данными с клиентом. Этот сокет прикрепляется к таблице файлов серверного процесса и его файловый дескриптор возвращается в вызове `accept`. Этот новосозданный сокет является клиентским, то есть через него можно ожидать данные (`recv`) или отправлять данные (`send`)

Что происходит дальше.

Все сервера устроены примерно одинаково. Как только `accept` где-то в дебрях серверного кода возвращает клиентский сокет, с ним связывается обработчик получаемых данных. Когда в сокет приходят данные от клиента, серверная инфраструктура находит обработчик и вызывает его (здесь я умышленно не пишу про `select`/`poll`). Так работает `gRPC`, так работает web-сервер.

### Ограничения

Серверная инфраструктура может накладывать различные ограничения на число подключений и объем трафика.

Во-первых, ядро ОС лимитирует количество файлов, открытых одним процессом. Клиентский сокет с точки зрения ОС - файл, поэтому этот лимит может привести к тому, что `accept` вернёт ошибку `too many open files`. Я недавно на такое налетел. Забыл поднять через `ulimit` предел, и через пару дней работы сервер `gRPC` падал именно с этой ошибкой. Накапливалось число открытых файлов `leveldb` и в какой-то недетерминированный момент опс - и сервер аварийно завершался.

Во-вторых, библиотека `gRPC`, которой вы пользуетесь, может лимитировать число подключений. Если `accept` возвращает новый сокет, а число открытых клиентских сокетов уже достигло заданного предела, новый сокет просто закрывается без прикрепления к нему обработчика.

В-третьих, библиотека может накладывать ограничения на число данных, получаемых из сокета. Так как вся работа с сокетами, как правило, инкапсулирована, и обработчик получает уже готовые данные, то для слишком активных сокетов обращение за новыми данными может происходить по таймеру. Скажем, через пару-тройку секунд после завершения обработчика, а не сразу после его завершения.

Первое ограничение смотрите в документации на ОС. В частности в Linux это утилита `ulimit`. Второе и третье в документации на библиотеку `gRPC`, которой вы пользуетесь.

Comment: т.е. фактически входная точка gRPC сама выступает "веб сервером", принимает все на одном порту, и раздает на другие сокеты? А на этой входной точке есть какое то ограничение кол-во в секунду например? или это уже зависит только от сети и т.п.?

Comment: @ПавелКозлов я добавил про сокеты и ограничения

Comment: получается если допустить что у нас большое кол-во ядер и т.п. мы можем создать огромное количество потоков. Но на входе из серверного сокета единомоментно у нас читает только 1 обработчик которые уже передает дальше на управление клиентским сокетам? Т.е. если вот прям в один момент обратиться 5 клиентов но даже если у нас есть 5 потоков разных, они все равно будут ожидать создания отдельных сокетов после обработки серверного?

Comment: @ПавелКозлов да, можно и так сказать. Поэтому в реальной жизни цикл с вызовами `accept` делают в отдельном потоке и стараются "выпихнуть" новосозданные клиентские сокеты в обработчики как можно быстрее.